# Parse/Split a forward slash delimited string

Tags: php, regex, parsing, text-extraction, csv

This is more of a generic regex question than a PHP-specific one.

I am given different strings that may look like:

> `A/B/PA ID U/C/D`

And I'm trying to extract the segment in the middle slashes that has spaces ("/PA ID U") using:

> `preg_match('/(\/PA .+)(\/.+|$)/', $string, $matches);`

However, instead of getting "/PA ID U" as I was expecting, I was getting "/PA ID U/C/D".

How can I make it prioritize matching "/.+" over "$" in that last group?

---

Additional notes:

I need that last group to match either another "/somethingsomthing" or "" because the string varies a lot.  If I only match for the "/.+", I won't be able to get the "/PA ID U" if it's at the end of the line, such as in "A/B/PA ID U".

Basically, I need to be able to extract specific segments like so:

> Given:  `"A/B/PA ID U/PA ID U/C/D"`
>
> Extract:  `(A), (B), (PA ID U), (PA ID U), (C), (D)`

---

[UPDATE]

I'm trying to avoid using `split()` or `explode()` because that would mean that I have to match the "PA ID U" pattern separately.  Aside from merely extracting the slash-separated segments, I need to validate that the substrings match specific patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is not working because the `.+` is being greedy. You could fix it by adding a non-greedy modifier (a `?`) to your first `.+` as such:

```
preg_match('/(\/PA .+?)(\/.+|$)/', '', $matches);
```

You could alternatively do:

```
'/\/(PA [^\/]+)(\/.+|$)/'
```

I moved the slash outside of the parens to avoid capturing that (I presume you're not interested in the slash). The `[^\/]+` will capture any character up to the next slash.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss here. I can't get this regex to extract the Given "A/B/PA ID U/PA ID U/C/D" into (A), (B), (PA ID U), (PA ID U), (C), (D). What regex flavor does php use? Perl? Pythong? Any other?

Comment: preg_match is implemented as a call to libpcre. PCRE = Perl Compatible Regular Expressions

Answer (score 2):

I think you can most effectively use split to accomplish what you want.

```
split('/',$string);
```

See: [php manual](https://www.php.net/split)

Answer (score 0):

necramirez,

```
(\w+\s?)+
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Either match by writing the delimiting character inside a negated character class or split using the delimiter as a literal character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8nki6))

```
$string = 'A/B/PA ID U/PA ID U/C/D';

// get only first value starting with PA:
echo preg_match('~PA[^/]+~', $string, $match) ? $match[0] : '';

echo "\n---\n";

// get all values strings with PA:
var_export(preg_match_all('~PA[^/]+~', $string, $matches) ? $matches[0] : []);

echo "\n---\n";

// get all delimited values:
var_export(explode('/', $string));
```

Output:

```
PA ID U
---
array (
  0 => 'PA ID U',
  1 => 'PA ID U',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'A',
  1 => 'B',
  2 => 'PA ID U',
  3 => 'PA ID U',
  4 => 'C',
  5 => 'D',
)
```